# Solution with Multiple ASP.NET MVC Projects in a Azure Website using the same domain with subdirectories (/app1, /app2)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I have a solution with multiple ASP.NET MVC projects that have to be accessed independently under the same domain:

- Main Website (domain.com)
- Employee's Panel (domain.com/employee)
- CMS (domain.com/cms)
- WebApi (domain.com/webapi)
- User's Panel (domain.com/users)

Publishing directly to an IIS enabled dedicated server I successufully managed to run these apps under the same domain.

But how to do that using Azure Websites? I found out that Azure Websites allow the configuration of Virtual Directories (as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site.aspx)), but I'm not sure the virtual directories support different applications as I need?

Answer (score 2):

After publishing my question, I found the solution in the related Stack Overflow questions. Virtual Directories are indeed the way to go, as detailed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx